# how to create momentum using rigid body

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to animate a perpetual motion machine, using rigid body physics like the one in the link here:https://www.youtube.com/shorts/yFuK68u2-hw

But I can't get the ball to gain enough momentum to launch off the railing.

I've messed around with the friction, weight, and damping, but it doesn't work.

is there a way to fix this with rigid body, or will I have to redo the physics?

thanks to anyone who responds.

Comment: And of course in physics there is no perpetual motion machine…so of course Bloop is right and you have to use other tricks like force fields (which you should keyframe) to make it possible

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Force Field](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/forces/force_fields/index.html) to accelerate the ball on the down ramp, adding enough force to continue the loop indefinitely. Setting the friction on everything to 0 also helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a question I agree with, and I apologize for not having a good answer. The person who replied above said to use a force field or remove all friction, but how do we remove all friction?

Comment: Your entry is a comment. I suggest to add it as a comment to the question instead of posting it as an answer. If you have a related question, I think it's best to ask it as a separate question. It will attract more attention like that and will be easier to find.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/182881)